# How do I add a newline to a windows-forms TextBox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, newline

I am trying to add a line of text to a TextBox component in VB.net, but I cannot figure out for the life of me how to force a new line. Right now it just adds onto what I have already, and that is not good.

I have tried copying the actual linebreaks, didn't work. I tried AppendText(), didn't work.

How on earth do I do this? It is multiline already.

Comment: Are we talking ASP.NET or WinForms?

Comment: Winforms. I do not know ASP.net

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try using [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx):

> Gets the newline string defined for this environment.

Something like this ought to work:

```
textBox.AppendText("your new text" & Environment.NewLine)
```

Answer (score 6):

Try something like

```
"Line 1" & Environment.NewLine & "Line 2"
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you set [AcceptsReturn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.acceptsreturn.aspx) property to true?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like:

textbox.text = "text" & system.environment.newline & "some more text"

Answer (score 2):

First you have to set the `MultiLine` property of the `TextBox` to `true` so that it supports multiple lines.

Then you just use `Environment.NewLine` to get the newline character combination.

Answer (score 2):

Try `vbCrLf`.

For example:

```
TextBox1.text = "line_one" & vbCrLf & "line_two"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TextBox2.Text = "Line 1" & Environment.NewLine & "Line 2"
```

or

```
TextBox2.Text = "Line 1"
TextBox2.Text += Environment.NewLine
TextBox2.Text += "Line 2"
```

This, is how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Quickie test code for WinForms in VB:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim Newline As String
    Newline = System.Environment.NewLine

    TextBox1.Text = "This is a test"
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & Newline & "This is line 2"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Took this from [JeffK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302804/how-do-i-add-a-newline-to-a-windows-forms-textbox/1302842#1302842) and made it a little more compact.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim Newline As String = System.Environment.NewLine

    TextBox1.Text = "This is a test"
    TextBox1.Text += Newline + "This is another test"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the text below!

```
TextBox1.Text = "This is a test"
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & ControlChars.Newline & "This is line 2"
```

The `controlchars.Newline` will automatically put `"This is line 2"` to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `vbNewLine` Object as in

```
MessageLabel.Text = "The Sales tax was:" & Format(douSales_tax, "Currency") & "." & vbNewLine & "The sale person: " & mstrSalesPerson
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you textbox is set for multiline then you wont need any extra dims vbnewline will work just fine

Answer (score 0):

The richtextbox also has a "Lines" property that is an array of strings. Each item in this array ends in an implicit line break and will be displayed on its own line.

If your text is static or has an initial value and you are using the designer in Visual Studio you can simply add lines directly there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

"This is line-1 \r\n This is line-2"

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use `vbCrLf`, which is a VB.NET character return.

```vb
console.writeline("This is the first line," & vbCrLf & "...and this is the second line.")
```

```
Output:
This is the first line,
...and this is the second line.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
       If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then SendKeys.Send("^{ENTER}") : TextBox1.Focus()
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I discovered that if you put the newline (e.g. vbCrLf) and the end of the appended text, it gets ignored. So you have to put it either in the middle, or at the beninning.

My example code to write a log line to the multi-line textbox (my textbox name is "textLog"):

```
Private Sub WriteLog(s As String)
    If textLog.Text = "" Then
        textLog.AppendText("s)
    Else
        textLog.AppendText(vbCrLf & "s)
    End If
    textLog.SelectionStart = textLog.Text.Length
    textLog.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub
```

As you may notice, it also moves the selection in a way that the last inserted text is always visible.