# New line in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Why, when I do im my code:

```
"Land Location \\r\\n Roundoff (C)"
```

I see the  `\\r\\n`  and not a new line feeder at the output?

Any idea how to do that?

As I said I must have only one string there, without using a "&". Can I put that `vbCrLf` inside of my string somehow?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302804/how-do-i-add-a-newline-to-a-windows-forms-textbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be "Land Location " & vbCR & vbLF .....

--

Edit: per [@JeffSahol's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815478/new-line-in-vb-net/1815483?noredirect=1#comment77114796_1815483), you can use [string interpolation](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-VB-14#string-interpolation) since VB 14, so it can be like

`$"...{vbCrLf}..."`

Comment: I must have it in the same string , and not starting adding it

Comment: it is 'in the same string', the compiler will concatenate constant strings

Comment: I must to see only one   string before compiling .
Is there some way to put the vbCrLf inside the string and not using & ?

Comment: You could do `String.Format("line 1{0}line 2", vbCrLf)`, but it's really still concatination

Comment: why MUST you 'see' one string? what difference does that make?

Comment: Localization has nothing to do with it.  A correctly localized string will replace your literal with a resource variable name.  That means a code change later anyway, and so it doesn't matter how much concatenation you're doing right now.

Comment: I am sorry but it is . If you want to put in the resources a full string and not parts of it ? So the translator will see the whole string that he has to translate and not parts of it .

Comment: As of VB 14, you can also use string interpolation to simplify: 
$"Land Location {vbCrLf} etc. etc. "

Comment: @JeffSahol, Thanks. Nice to know that.

Answer (score 10):

There is no \ escape codes in VB so you can't put a line break in a string literal. The only escape character in VB strings is the double quotation marks used to insert a quotation mark in a string.

You can use the VB constant for a Windows type line break:

```
"Land Location " & vbCrLf & " Roundoff (C)"
```

For the code to be platform independent, you should use the NewLine property instead:

```
"Land Location " & Environment.NewLine & " Roundoff (C)"
```

Whether you should use the platform independent code or not depends on the situation.

If you need it as a single string for some reason, you would have to use a marker for the line break, that you replace when you use the string:

```
Dim s As String = "Land Location \n Roundoff (C)"
s = Replace(s, "\n", Environment.NewLine)
```

Comment: @steven: What are you talking about? Where and why would String.Format make any more sense?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of including the newline manually in the String use [System.Environment.NewLine.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)

Comment: +1. This is the recommended way of doing it, but 99 times out of 100 it is unlikely you will be swapping to Linux (say).

Comment: It was tagged as VB.net. Also... it helps with porting the code over to C# as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
vbCrLf
vbCr
vbLf
```

Comment: I must have all written as one string .